# Probability and random numbers

Tags: c++, random, probability

I am just starting with C++ and am creating a simple text-based adventure. I am trying to figure out how to have probability based events. For example a 50% chance that when you open box there will be a sword and a 50% chance it will be a knife. I know how to make a random number generator, but I don't know how to associate that number with something. I created a variation of what I want but it requires the user to input the random number. I am wondering how to base the if statement on whether or not the random number was greater or less than 50, not if the number the user put in was greater or less than 50.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rest operator % with rand.
rand()%2 can give you either 0 or 1.
Lets 0 be a sword and 1 be a knife.

If you also need an axe,then use rand()%3.
It can give you 0,1 or 2.
2 represents an axe and 0 and 1 like above.
The ifs and elses are then obvious.

rand()%n where n is a big number has a higher probability to give you smaller numbers. The probability is not equally distributed. You can check out some random number generators from stl or boost.

Answer (score 0):

You speak of probability based events, so I'll explain in terms of random items.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(){
//you create an array or another similar data structure, that has an index
//each index will respond to an event/item/anything really
std::string event[5]={"axe","sword","knive","bow","nothing"};

//now you create the index for the array to return the item
//we will be using the rand function for this
//the % operator returns the rest from a division with 5
int index = rand()%5;

//since an array starts from 0 and & returns 0-4, we can just plop index into event
std::cout<<"you get a "<<event[index];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use [`rand()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) it generates numbers in the range `0..RAND_MAX`. So for a 50% probability you could do something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (rand() < RAND_MAX / 2)
{
    // sword - 50% probability
}
else
{
    // knife - 50% probability
}
```

You can obviously extend this to more than two different cases with any given probability for each case, simply by defining appropriate thresholds in the range `0..RAND_MAX` for each case, e.g.

```
int r = rand();

if (r < RAND_MAX / 4)
{
    // sword - 25% probability
}
else if (r < 3 * RAND_MAX / 4)
{
    // knife - 50% probability
}
else
{
    // axe - 25% probability
}
```